# Enable prevention of accidental deletions of DNS zones stored in Active Directory Domain Services (ADDS)

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory

I want prevent accidental deletion for my dns zones on my domain. I have try to perform this action via powershell but i have some doubts.
I have used the following command, i found this on Microsoft:

```bsh
Get-ADobject -Server "<DomainController_fqdn>" -Filter {objectclass -eq "DNSZone"} -SearchBase "DC=DomainDNSZones,<DomainDN>" | Set-ADObject -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $true
```

Bellow is this command adapted to my domain:

```bsh
Get-ADobject -Server "myservername+fqdn" -Filter {objectclass -eq "mydominzone"} -SearchBase "DC=DomainDNSZones,DC=aa,DC=bb,DC=cc" | Set-ADObject -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $true
```

The script seems to run ok , but I don't receive any message that that fag was changed on "true".
How can i check if this setting was applied or not?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to tell `Get-ADObject` to show that property with the `-Properties` parameter:

```
Get-ADobject -Server "myservername+fqdn" `
             -Filter {objectclass -eq "mydominzone"} `
             -SearchBase "DC=DomainDNSZones,DC=aa,DC=bb,DC=cc" `
             -Properties ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion
```

Interestingly, there isn't actually any flag in Active Directory for that. All it does is add a "deny delete" permission for "Everyone" to the account. But both `Set-ADObject` and `Get-ADObject` translate that into a property that you can set and read. And even AD Users and Computers shows it as a checkbox.